# Max number of rows that can be fetched using WCF

Tags: wcf, rows

How many rows can I fetch using WCF service ? Is there a upper limit to the number of rows that can be returned using WCF service ?

Answer (score 2):

There isnt an upper limit, if you need more then what is availabe at the time, you need to change the limit in the response, the default is 65536

modify the web.config file to change this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734663.aspx